# Modes of C++ file handling

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

[Look this example 2 comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAnEX.png)
***Difference between trunc and out mode in C++?***
trunc and out are the two modes for ofstream. We know that truct deletes the data before the data before writing new data into the file whereas out mode just overwrites it.
 I cannot find difference in the working of both the modes? Please explain the difference in detail with example? Please consider the fact that I have just started with programming and don't have much experience.

Comment: The different modes are described here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open It isn't clear what the specific question is you're asking about them.

Comment: My question is that if there exist a file and we just open it with trunc mode or out mode then in both the cases the data of the file will be removed and then new data will be added from the begining. So what is the difference in using trunc mode or out mode.

Comment: Modes stack with other modes. `out` can stack with `in` and the file will no longer default to truncation. I find [this chart From the C++ Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/file.streams#filebuf.members-3) coupled with this [description of the C file open modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen#File_access_flags) to be extremely helpful, but that could be because I came into C++ after writing quite a lot of C.

Comment: Thanks but explanation in regards with C++ will be more helpful

Comment: That's kind of the problem. C++ defines what the modes do in terms of C. You need to do a table join of the C and C++ tables to figure out what really happens.

Comment: But the point is `out` does not always `trunc`

Comment: Share code snippets instead of their pics

Answer (score 1):

Mode behaviour changes as you stack modes with other modes. For example, when you stack `out` with `in` the file will no longer be truncated when opened.

C++ defines what the modes do in terms of C, so in order to understand the behaviour you need to join [this chart From the C++ Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/file.streams#filebuf.members-3) with [this description of the C file open modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen#File_access_flags).

| in | out | trunc | app | Explanation | already exists | does not exist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | + |  |  | Create a file for writing | destroy contents | create new |
|  | + | + |  | Create a file for writing | destroy contents | create new |
|  | + |  | + | Append to a file | write to end | create new |
|  |  |  | + | Append to a file | write to end | create new |
| + |  |  |  | Open a file for reading | read from start | failure to open |
| + | + |  |  | Open a file for read/write | read from start | error |
| + | + | + |  | Create a file for read/write | destroy contents | create new |
| + | + |  | + | Open a file for read/write | write to end | create new |
| + |  |  | + | Open a file for read/write | write to end | create new |

I have omitted `binary` because it's the same as `text` but without character translation.